# Special characters in Emacs dired and attachment paths on Windows 7: "\374" instead of "ü" displayed

Tags: windows-7, emacs, path, encoding, dired

I want to use `dired+` in `Emacs` for browsing directory paths on Windows 7.

I'm having problems with special characters like äöü in `dired` mode and in attachment paths:

### dired

- When I'm trying to access a directory with `M-x dired`, the displayed path contains strange characters like e.g.

  - "\374" for "ü"
  - or "\366" for "ö".

Same is true for directory and file listings displayed by `dired`.

**Is there a setting which can make `dired` display the characters with the correct encoding?**

### Attachment paths

my **other problem** seems to be **related***:

- I currently added a long server path as attachment directory in org-mode, like
  `//servername/dir1/dir2/dir2/dir4/etcetera/Zubehör/`
  (I usually copy the UNC path in Windows 7 Explorer with the PathCopy context menu)

The path is shown like that in :ATTACH_DIR: in the properties with the "ö" correctly displayed.
However, when I type `C-c C-a C-f` to open the directory in Windows Explorer, it creates a new directory at the same path called **ZubehÃ¶r** and then opens this oneinstead of the right one.

How can I solve those 2 problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Emacs bug, not a **Dired+** bug, I believe.  Emacs on Windows cannot handle Unicode chars in file names.  This has been filed as a bug since at least 2010, but it was relegated to the "wishlist", so it's unclear when or whether it will ever be fixed.

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15236

**Description of a possible fix**

> The problem is that the mainline Emacs code uses APIs that don't
>   accept wide characters.  Examples include 'stat', 'access', 'open',
>   'fopen', etc.  To fix the problem, we'd need to provide our own
>   implementation of these APIs that would accept a UTF-8 encoded file
>   name, then re-encode the file name in UTF-16, and call the Unicode
>   APIs as part of the implementation.  This is a large job.

source: [Subject: Re: AW: bug#12807: 24.2; Emacs cannot edit file with funny Unicode characters in the file     name    on Windows; Date: Tue, 06 Nov 2012 05:57:45 +0200](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=12807)

## solved in Emacs 24.4

IT finally works in `Gnu Emacs 24.4`

Comment: thanks for your help! However I wonder how this essential feature can be on the "wishlist" for years. This is an essential feature which makes me think if I have to stop using Emacs on Windows. I'm always avoiding special characters in file and path names, but I have to work with network drives where other people saev information who don't care about that. Is it possible to donate money for the fix of a special problem (like that)?

Comment: Tell Emacs Dev - every voice helps.  But FWIW, this is the response I got when I said the same thing today in the [bug thread](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15236#18): *"Wishlist" just means it's a missing feature, as opposed to a bug in
an existing feature.  It doesn't say anything about the importance of
the feature that is missing.*

Comment: yes, I read that discussion. Thanks a lot for your help!